# Why is the 'quot' entity not being escaped?

Tags: saxon

When I run

```
(let [processor  (Processor.)
      builder    (.newDocumentBuilder processor)
      xdm-node   (.build builder
                   (StreamSource.
                     (StringReader.
                       "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>&quot;a</body></html>")))
      serializer (doto (.newSerializer processor)
                   (.setOutputProperty Serializer$Property/METHOD "html"))]
  (println (.getSaxonProductVersion processor) (.getSaxonEdition processor))
  (.serializeNodeToString serializer xdm-node))
```

I get

```
12.3 HE
=> "<!DOCTYPE HTML>\n<html>\n   <body>\"a</body>\n</html>"
```

while I would expect

```
12.3 HE
=> "<!DOCTYPE HTML>\n<html>\n   <body>&quot;a</body>\n</html>"
```

What am I missing?

Comment: It's not inside an attribute, why do you expect `"` to become `&quot;` there? Both snippets you show are perfectly valid HTML. Your serializer writes tokens according to some inbuilt standard, so `<!DOCTYPE html>` was translated to `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`, and quote entity - to actual quote, since it's harmless.

Comment: I thought `"` needs to be escaped everywhere.

Comment: Where do base that thought on? Neither XML nor HTML require you to escape a double quote `"`, unless you use it inside of an attribute value already delimited with double quotes e.g. `<foo bar="He said: &quot; ... &quot;"/>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The serializer will escape anything that needs to be escaped. Quotes and apostrophes only need to be escaped in attribute values.